# Best way to set environment-specific variables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, development-environment, production-environment

There are certain variables I would like to have in the development environment, and certain variables for the production environment. For example, in production mode, I might want to use a cache to speed up performance. I have couple of open-ended questions about this:

Question: What is the easiest and fastest way to set environment variables in a rails app? For example, `ENV["USE_CACHE"] = true` in production, and `= false` in development.

If you could point to a specific gem, and/or the specific files I'd need to touch, that would be most helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Зелёный The article you mentioned is very, very old.

Comment: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt few things about `ENV` variables this [discussion](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Setting-secrettoken-value-120725.S.5957798212940161027?view=&gid=120725&item=5957798212940161027&type=member&commentID=discussion%3A5957798212940161027%3Agroup%3A120725&trk=hb_ntf_COMMENTED_ON_GROUP_DISCUSSION_YOU_CREATED#commentID_discussion%3A5957798212940161027%3Agroup%3A120725)

You can set `ENV` varaibles by just appending

```
export USE_CACHE=true
```

to your **.bashrc** file.

...and in your application you can use

```
ENV["USE_CACHE"]
```

,
you can also check out [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) and [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) which are application specific.

For your purpose just use

```
if Rails.env.eql?("development")
 #do stuff
end
```

Its upto you choose easiest and fastest way!